# Highlight text of emails in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, highlighting

Seems like this should be fairly simple, but I can't find a simple solution.

Is it possible to highlight the content of emails received in Outlook 2010 without creating an entirely new message?

Comment: Can you elaborate: Do you want the bodies of incoming e-mails to be highlighted, so when you reply it is highlighted, or do you want the list of new e-mails in the Inbox to be highlighted?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I'm talking about highlighting the content of the email, as in the common use case of marking up important passages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1 -** Open the received message.

**Step 2 -** Click Actions / Edit Message on the Ribbon, Message tab

[image]

**Step 3 -** Now select your text and click Highlight on the Format Text tab

[image]

**Step 4 -** Click Save on the Quick Access bar to make changes permanent

[image]

**Before and After example:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect, thanks @DaveBecker. However, the format I put in shows in my reply to the person, OMG! I should be able to put in anything I want without jeopardising the email conversation or confusing other people, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand you correctly. These three actions will allow you to highlight text in outlook 2010 but I think something a little more elaborate is required.  If so, please elaborate in your question.

1. You can just highlight the text with the mouse.
2. Open the format text tab in the ribbon.
3. Click the "Text Highlight Color" button to highlight the text to a color of your choice.